# how dynamically signin to a pop3 email is possible?

Tags: java, email, smtp, pop3

I want to know how application like Thunderbird, Outlook can dynamically login a email account (like gmail) only with one username and one password.

Do they keep the famous server login configs (ex: gmail, hotmail, yahoo) in their own database and in login request those info fetchs from their database and merge with username and password for loginning mechanism or there is another mechanism **(like requesting to vender email provider for fetching these data)** which I don't know ?

Answer (score 0):

Local applications like those normally use local storage (like SQLite or a text file) to store user data. Sometime in plaintext or, better, encrypted.